# Cumulative Normal Distribution.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from $f(X;\theta)=\phi_{\theta,25}$, that is, $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be normally distributed with mean $\theta$ and variance $25$.

I am not understanding how
$$sup_{\theta\leq17}[\phi(\frac{17+\frac{5}{\sqrt n}-\theta}{\frac{5}{\sqrt n}})]=\phi(1)$$
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi$ is unimodal, decreasing on the positive reals, and reaches its maximum, $1$, at $0$. Here, this implies that since $\theta \leq17$, the argument is positive and decreasing in $\theta$: the overall function is thus increasing wrt $\theta$, and therefore maximum at the upper boundary $17$.

Comment: The value of the standard normal density function at its mode is not unity - you forget the normalizing constant.

Comment: Oh, yes -- but that doesn't change the argument.